# Jwt Authentication in multiple app

Tags: angularjs, zend-framework, laravel-5, jwt

I have two applications, one is in zend and other is in laravel+angular restful application. The Laravel is serverside restful and Angular is frontend. The laravel uses Jwt token based authentications. Now the requirement is to share the login information accross zend and laravel. When the logged in user from the angular app clicks in the link to zend application, the user needs to get authenticated with the same token available from laravel.
Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Does the Zend application have access to the same db?

Comment: Yes both have access to same db.

Comment: OK, then let the Zend app authenticates through the same jwt token.